# Docker pull stops mid-pull and shows nothing in my files or in the docker interface

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

Initial:
I'm using Windows 10, running docker command on the powershell. My Local disk space is low but I'm running this on my hard disk (D:).

Command line:

```
PS D:\Biop\CLARA_method> docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia/clara-train-sdk:v3.1.01
v3.1.01: Pulling from nvidia/clara-train-sdk
7595c8c21622: Pulling fs layer
d13af8ca898f: Pulling fs layer
**{...
...
...
...
more of the same codes and either "Pulling fs layer" or "Waiting"}**
c18477ba8094: Waiting
b97dab84d0d6: Waiting
6bb9b0853045: Pulling fs layer
2c75b980ef51: Pulling fs layer
f41e15600a89: Pulling fs layer
f7d0f7f7c600: Waiting
44057ff905c4: Pulling fs layer
ef24ea424719: Waiting
26f07601bfd2: Waiting

open /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob439951377: read-only file system
```

Effect:
There's no file at the file location mentioned, I don't even know if anything downloaded at all.

**Please let me know if more information is needed this is my first time on StackOverflow**

Comment: How long have you waited? I have had some really bad performance pulling images on windows 10. Sometimes 10+ minutes for an image <200mb

Comment: Read only filesystem sounds like you filled up the disk. Docker runs in a VM on Mac and Windows, so this is the disk space you've allocated to that embedded VM, not your windows drive itself.

Comment: I forgot to reply, yeah my disk is very full right now and I'm searching for ways to change the docker path to D drive